# Data retrieval from Access file into DataTable not working

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have some code to connect a database with the program, but for some reason at run time it does not show the data from the DB.

```
Public Class Form2

Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\employee\employee.accdb")
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("", con)
Dim empDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim empTable As New DataTable
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.EmpTableAdapter.Fill(Me.EmpDataSet.emp)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from emp", con)
    empDA = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from emp", con)
    empDA.Fill(empTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = empDA
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question looks to be a bit muddled as to what needs to be done.

Variables should be limited to the minimum scope that they are needed in, and some things need to be disposed of after use (to avoid memory leaks, files remaining locked, and other problems with computer resources).

For the disposal, the [`Using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) is useful as it makes sure that that is done automatically.

You should try to put each logical piece of code in a suitably small method so that it is easier to work with. Perhaps something like this:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2

    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\employee.accdb"

    Sub ShowEmployeeData()
        Dim sql = "SELECT [Id], [FirstName] FROM [Employees] ORDER BY [Id]"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                Dim employees As New DataTable()
                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(employees)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = employees
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub


    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ShowEmployeeData()

    End Sub

End Class
```

So the `connStr` variable is available everywhere in the class `Form2`, and the code that shows the employee data is in its own Sub.

When querying a database, you should specify the actual columns that you need, so that the columns are returned in the order you want, and order by one of the columns so that the data is returned in a predicatable order - databases are free to give you any order for anything if you don't tell them otherwise.

Comment: Thank you sir, your advice is really help.
The code works good now. thank you!

Comment: I have a couple of small critiques. Firstly, there's no need to use nested `Using` blocks when there is no code between them. You can create multiple objects with a single `Using` statement. Secondly, there's no point to creating a command object explicitly because you can pass the same SQL text and connection object to the data adapter constructor and let it create the command.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Both valid points, but I left it flexible so that if someone copies that code and wants to use SQL parameters in a different query then it will be easy to do so. Also, C# doesn't allow combining usings where the variables are of different types, so it's easier to translate to that if someone wants to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while you have some tips and suggestions, I'll give a few more.

First, try using the project setting to create the connection. The reason for this is not only can you create + test + make a connection, you can do this without code.

so, try this to build + create the connection:

[image]

so now click on the [...] and it will launch the connection builder for you!

So you now get this:

[image]

(use the change button if it defaulted to sql server).

So, using the above allows you to build ONE connection - one that you can use for the WHOLE application.

And there is the handy test connection button!!

So, in above we called the connection "MyDB".

That way we don't have messy connection strings in code, and we have ONE place to change/set the connection.

Now, in code?
Well, as a really nice tip?

```
You often need a connection
You often need a data reader.
and you need some sql (command text).
```

So, in place of declaring that reader, declaring the conneciton, and all that jazz?

use a command object!

Why?
because the command object has ALL of the above 3 objects in one nice simple ONE object.
As a result, you don't have to declare the 3 separate objects.

Just use and adopt a command object in MOST cases.

So, now our code has this:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class DataGridTest1
    Private Sub DataGridTest1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName from tblHotels",
                    New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.MyDB))

            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData


        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Note how simple - and how few variables we have to setup and declare.

So, I find this becomes quite much as easy as using Access or even writing older VB6 code.

So, try the above - its very little code, and use the connection builder in the "settings" for the application - thus removing the need to introduce connection strings all over the place in code.

Comment: Thanks sir, I know this way and I tried to use it, but I could not know how to update the data or delete them using it's code, I also had a problem that when I run the project and add data on the gridview, then stop the project and run it again, I cant find the data I added even in the database I connect with it!

Comment: sadly, in my college they teach us the old visual basic and the old ways to write it's code.
that is why I could not understand that much about it :(

Comment: Well, even visual studio 2013 should look and work near identical to above. and Visual Studio Express 2019 is what I used for above - and it also free. So, it not clear why a older version (2013) is being used, since VS 2019 (Express) is really nice and is a 100% free to download and use as you please.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal It could be useful to set the scope of the setting to "User" instead of "Application" so that the user can set the location of the database. And that is just one entrance to the rabbit warren that I didn't take in my answer ;)

Comment: yes, I think the per-user only tends to make sense if the user can choose/set the database. But that's actually a "common" use case.  however, in most cases, the application is on the computer - and application wide does and should suffice in most cases. I think for starting out? Just use application - and it will work for the user.  And if one say used c:\MyCoolApp\MyApp.exe as always the same location, then deploying to each computer will and should work - and not care about "user". Introducing "user" concepts to this new user probably more then they can handle right now.